# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object when deleting the key of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to delete the key from an object of the object if their value is null and type of key is optional.

for example i have interface of the object like this:

```
Interface IObject {
  amount: number;
  plan: IPlan;
  achieve: IAchieve;
  status?: string;
  rank?: number;
}

Interface IPlan {
  year: string | null;
  name: string;
  date?: Date;
  grade?: number;
}

Interface IAchieve {
  pic: string;
  name?: string;
  date?: Date;
  grade?: number;
}
```

and have value:

```
let data: IObject = {
     amount: 2300;
     plan: {
       year: null;
       name: 'renov';
       date: null;
       grade: 3;
     };
     achieve: {
      pic: 'John';
      name: null;
      date: null;
      grade: 3;
    };
     status: 'good';
     rank: null;
  };
```

what i did:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(obj => {
    if (typeof data[obj as keyof typeof IObject] === 'object') {
      Object.keys(data[obj as keyof typeof any]).forEach(obj2 => {
        if (data[obj as keyof typeof any][obj2] == undefined) {
            delete data[obj as keyof typeof any][obj2];
        }
      });
    }
    else if (data[obj as keyof typeof any] == undefined) delete data[obj as keyof typeof any];
  });
```

but i get:

> **"TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"**

I'm expecting result:

```
data = {
     amount: 2300;
     plan: {
       year: null;
       name: 'renov';
       grade: 3;
     };
     achieve: {
      pic: 'John';
      grade: 3;
    };
     status: 'good';
  };
```

Comment: in which line is the error ... start seeking there ... i guess, your indexation is wrong.

Comment: To me it seems as if you're trying to access Typescript type information at runtime (during execution of your code), which is impossible.
Or I misunderstand what you are doing.

Comment: @helle at  delete data[obj as keyof typeof any][obj2];

Comment: are you sure you want data.plan.year inside your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with this question.

## Syntax issues

- `interface` not `Interface`.
  See [Everyday Types: Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces)
- When creating objects use a `,` separator between fields instead of `;`.
  See [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).
- A field with type `date?: Date` should accept `Date` and `undefined`. If you want to include `null`, then you should write it as `date?: Date | null`.
  See [Everyday Types: `null` and `undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined).
- The [typescript variant of `typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) can only be used to retrieve the type of a variable or property. `typeof IObject` would try to get the type of an interface, which will not work.

  - I don't understand what you're trying to do with lines like this: `obj as keyof typeof any`.

## Functionality issue

> I want to delete the key from an object of the object if their value is null and type of key is optional.

If I understand this line correctly then you're trying to use the interface definition to do something at runtime.
This will **not** work, after the typescript has been compiled into javascript, the interfaces will no longer be present in your code.
See [The Basics: Erased Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types).

You'll need to tackle this problem from a different angle.

Perhaps you could just remove all fields with a value of `null` from your object no matter what?
If your typings are correct, then this should only touch the fields that are actually nullable.